# How to find the value that has maximum duplicates in app engine datastore using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I have a datastore that stores the cab booking details of the customers. In the admin console I need to display the statistics to the admin, like busiest location, peak hours, total bookings in a particular location in a particular day. For the busiest location i need to retrieve the location from where most number of cabs has been booked. Should I iterate through the entire datastore and keep a count or is there any method to know which location has maximum and minimum duplicates.

I am using a ajax call to java servlet which should return the busiest location.

And I also need a suggestion for maintaining such a stats page. Should I keep a separate Entity kind just for counters and stats and update it everytime when a customer books a cab or is the logic correct for iterating through the entire datastore for the stats page.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class has a method [`frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 1):

There are too many unknowns about your data model and usage patterns to offer a specific solution, but I can offer a few tips.

1. Updating a counter every time you create a new record will increase your writing costs by 2 write operations, which may or may not be significant.
2. Using keys-only queries is very cheap and fast. It is the preferred method for counting something, so you should try to model your data in such a way that a keys-only query can give you an answer. For example, if a "trip" entity has a property for "id of a starting point", and this property is indexed, you can loop through your locations using a keys-only query to count the number of trips that started from each location.

Assuming that you record a lot of trips, and that an admin page will be visited/refreshed not very frequently, the keys-only queries approach is the way to go. If the admin page is visited/refreshed many times per hour, you may be better off with the counters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My BookingDetails entity kind has BookingID(primary key), cabType, customerID, dateOfBooking, pickupDate, pickupLocation, dropLocation, pickupTime and contactDetails. Right now I am just fetching all the entities and displaying the stats. Like retrieving booking history of a particular customer I use query and filter and for totalBooking today I compare today's date with pickupDate to display Bookings Today stats. So is it good to fetch the entire datastore and go through each and every entity?

Comment: It all depends on how many entities you have, how frequently you create new entities, and how frequently you need the stats. There is no write or wrong answer here - only optimization based on your specific use case. If you don't have too many entities, start with the most straight-forward solution, and then optimize from there when and if necessary.